# How to copy ssh-copy-id to vagrant guest os from host os

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I've created a vagrant guest machine. Below is the `Vagrantfile` -

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/lunar64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.memory = "1024"
   end
end
```

When I do ping to the guest machine it works fine from host machine.

```bash
$ ping -c 3 192.168.33.10
PING 192.168.33.10 (192.168.33.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.606 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.588 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.33.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms

--- 192.168.33.10 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2031ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.301/0.498/0.606/0.139 ms
```

Now I would like `ssh-copy-id` from host machine into guest os.
I know I can ssh into vagrant using command `vagrant ssh`. But I would like to ssh using IP address of the guest OS like `ssh 192.168.33.10`.

But I'm getting below error -

```bash
$ ssh-copy-id 192.168.33.10
The authenticity of host '192.168.33.10 (192.168.33.10)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:Ultxy8OXuoD+ftDsJvy19fYbJNBS/znIukm+39GNdLE.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 2 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
rajkumar@192.168.33.10: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I would like do this way because I'm learning ansible playbooks using vagrant.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: remove the already existing key and regenerate the key in question. this is how i do it usually. but remind that you need to verify that the pubkey auth is enabled for sshd